# Как кратко вывести элементы массива

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Нужно вывести через пробел слова, записанные в массив из 7 объектов.
Интересует как сделать этот код короче:

```
System.out.println(masyv[0] + " " + masyv[1] + " " + masyv[2] + " " + masyv[3] +" " + 
        masyv[4] + " " + masyv[5] + " " + masyv[6]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `masyv` - это `String[]`, то можно воспользоваться методом [String.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) из Java 8:

```
String[] masyv = { "a1", "b2", "c3", "d4", "e5", "f6", "g7" };
System.out.println(String.join(" ", masyv));
```

И массив - это всё же `array`, а не `masyv`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно циклом

```
for (Class clazz: masyv)
    System.out.print(clazz+" ");
```

Comment: Можно подробнее описать данный способ?

Comment: @yamaha373 Что конкретно вам не ясно?